# Is it possible to draw a stacked density graph like this one in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, graph-visualization

Is it possible to draw a stacked density graph like this one in d3.js?

[image: NYC 911 calls]

Reference: http://www.wired.com/2010/11/ff_311_new_york/

Comment: Yes. that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it certainly is. `d3.layout.stack` is what you're looking for:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060954

Comment: Thanks for your great help